# How do I make my custom theme apply to my site only, NOT the admin?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm creating 100% custom theme for a DNN website. Whenever I apply it, the admin pages also get the theme. I don't want that nor need it. The admin should stay with the default theme it came with.

I'm on Admin > Themes and when I select my theme, I don't get any options to only apply to the Site and not the Admin.

How can I fix this? I'm I doing it the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the "ADMIN" page (click on Admin). Go to the PAGE SETTINGS on that page.

Choose the skin for that page. Choose the apply to children option as well so that it propagates to all the "child" pages of the Admin page.

You likely will want to do the same on the HOST page.

Chris

Comment: Great, that worked! I'm disappointed it's so hard to intuitively figure out, but still good. Thanks!